# Windows 10 HyperV no Network on VM

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, windows-10, hyper-v

I've followed instructions such as:

http://www.download3k.com/articles/How-to-add-an-XP-Mode-Virtual-Machine-to-Windows-10-or-8-using-Hyper-V-00770

and

http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2087-hyper-v-virtualization-setup-use-windows-10-a.html

to try and get a Windows XP virtual machine set up since installing Windows 10. Getting the machine set up and working was no problem with the Hyper-V Manager. But, I can't seem to get the XP machine to recognize a network adapter.

Just like the tutorials, it's set to use the virtual switch I created. I've tried every combination of settings I can think of under the settings but I can't seem to get it to work.

Does anybody know if there's something I'm missing? I can always try something like VirtualBox, but I was hoping to use this since it's already baked in with the OS.

Comment: Almost three days with no votes and no replies... Is there anything else I can do to improve the question? Is it missing any information? Is it off-topic for the site? Bueller?

Answer (score 2):

The usual network adapter in hyper-v won't work in XP.
Instead, use add hardware and add a legacy network adapter and set it as the network adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by using VirtualBox instead. IF anyone ever comes across a fix or has any suggestions, I'd love to get this working with Hyper-V.